# How to use sine in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am asking to use SymPy to solve a differential equation, y'=(2y-3y^2)sin(x).

Here is my code

```
import math
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
from IPython.display import display_latex
import sympy.plotting as sym_plot

# Define the equation
x = sym.symbols('x')
y = sym.Function('y')
eq1 = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x),(2*y(x)-3*(y(x))**2)*sin(x))
print("The equation")
display_latex(eq1)

# Solve the equation
eq1sol = sym.dsolve(eq1, y(x))
print("has solutions")
display_latex(eq1sol)
print("or equivalently")
display_latex(sym.simplify(eq1sol))
```

However, I got the name `'sin'` is not defined.

When I try to use `math.sin` instead, it says,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 11
      9 x = sym.symbols('x')
     10 y = sym.Function('y')
---> 11 eq1 = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x),(2*y(x)-3*(y(x))**2)*math.sin(x))
     12 print("The equation")
     13 display_latex(eq1)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py:351, in Expr.__float__(self)
    349 if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    350     raise TypeError("Cannot convert complex to float")
--> 351 raise TypeError("Cannot convert expression to float")

TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

Comment: You could use `sym.sin(x)`. This will use the `sin` function from within `sympy`.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: See [Sympy sin docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.sin)

Comment: so i don't need to `imort math` at all?

Comment: No, you don't need to import math if you're not using anything from within it.

Comment: okay, thank you guys, its really a stupid question :(

Comment: The errors are telling you there's no 'python' `sin`, and that `math.sin` expects a number, a float.  `x` is a `symbol`.  In general, use `sympy` functions when available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering an error because the sin function is not defined in your code. To use trigonometric functions like sin, you need to import them from the sympy library since you're using sympy for symbolic mathematics. Here's the modified code with the necessary import statement

```
import math
import sympy as sym
from sympy import sin  # Add this import statement
sym.init_printing()
from IPython.display import display_latex
import sympy.plotting as sym_plot

# Define the equation
x = sym.symbols('x')
y = sym.Function('y')
eq1 = sym.Eq(y(x).diff(x),(2*y(x)-3*(y(x))**2)*sin(x))
print("The equation")
display_latex(eq1)

# Solve the equation
eq1sol = sym.dsolve(eq1, y(x))
print("has solutions")
display_latex(eq1sol)
print("or equivalently")
display_latex(sym.simplify(eq1sol))
```